# Manage AWS Elastic Load Balancer instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to be able to massively add/remove instances from my Elastic Load Balancers, as I currently have to do this often for ~20 load balancers each time.

How can I automate this process through a script?

Comment: Have you looked at the AWS CLI tool? Are you using Auto-scaling Groups? What scripting language would you want to write this in?

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, help support the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96256/practical-cloud-computing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [ELB and ASG lifecycle event scripts](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-codedeploy-samples/tree/master/load-balancing/elb) in the [`aws-codedeploy-samples`](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-codedeploy-samples/tree/master/load-balancing/elb) GitHub repository. They include [`deregister_from_elb.sh`](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-codedeploy-samples/blob/master/load-balancing/elb/deregister_from_elb.sh) which will remove an instance from all (or a list) of Load Balancers / Auto Scaling Groups it is currently registered to, and the inverse [`register_with_elb.sh`](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-codedeploy-samples/blob/master/load-balancing/elb/register_with_elb.sh), which will (re-)register an instance with all (or a list) of the Load Balancers / Auto Scaling Groups it was previously registered to.